# Prove if $p>q$ then $L^{p} \subset L^{q}$ and $L_{\infty}\subset \bigcap^{\infty}_{1\leq p\leq \infty} L^p$

Tags: measure-theory

Prove if $p>q$ then $L^{p}(A) \subset L^{q}(A)$ and $L_{\infty}\subset \bigcap^{\infty}_{1\leq p\leq \infty} L^p$
NotE: $m(A)<\infty$

**My attempt:**

For the first part:

As $q<p<\infty$ then let $\phi(x)=x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ no this function is convex.

By Jensen inequality we have:

$$\phi (\int|f|^p)\leq\int\phi(|f|^p)$$

Then:

$${(\int |f|^q)}^\frac{p}{q}\leq\int|f|^p$$

this implies

$$||f||_q \leq ||f||_p$$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Jensen's inequality is applied to finite measure spaces..for instance $L^2(\Bbb{R} \subsetneq L^1(\Bbb{R}).$

Comment: These statements don't always hold when the measure space is not finite.

Comment: @DavidKraemer sorry, i edit my answer: $m(A)<\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jensen's inequality works only when $m(A)=1$. If $A = [0,2]$, $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $f \equiv 1/2$, then you have
$$||f||_2 = \left(\int_0^2 |1/2|^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < 1 = \int_0^2|1/2| = ||f||_1$$

You can, however, easily modify your proof by normalizing $m$.

For the $L_\infty$ part take $f \in L_\infty$ and $p \in [1,\infty)$, then $|f| \leq ||f||_\infty$ a.e., therefore
$$\left(\int_A |f|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \left(\int_A ||f||_\infty^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}= m(A)^{\frac{1}{p}} ||f||_\infty < \infty,$$
which proves that $f \in L_p$.